# how to replicate "WEB-INF/resources/apps/xbl/orbeon/us-state"

Tags: orbeon

I try replicate the example with  file "zip-states.xpl" in diretory "WEB-INF\resources\apps\xforms-sandbox\services" and files directory /WEB-INF/resources/apps/xbl/orbeon/us-state.

In my case, the first file (zip-states.xpl),I changed the value from select="doc('/xbl/orbeon/us-state/states.xml')/states/state  to select="doc('/xbl/orbeon/colombia/states.xml')/states/state.

After, I copied the files from "apps/xbl/orbeon/us-state" to  "apps/xbl/orbeon/colombia", and change file name us-state.xbl to colombia.xbl

In file colombia.xbl, I changed value from "src="oxf:/xbl/orbeon/us-state/state.xml" to src="oxf:/xbl/orbeon/colombia/state.xml" and I  go to the test form , but its not working.

I try created the same case, for change the value in state.xml for colombia states  but in other file.

Please, I hope you can help me

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you check the `orbeon.log`, and see if you can find any error in there that would put in you on the right track? You'll let us know if this helps.

Comment: You rigth , the log show me the error in xml file:Fatal error:                    XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.    I am review the zip-cities_mt05.xpl y zip-flat_mt03.xml.  The link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Tn41bPcuyoTnJReDJYeFZ3aEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool! When doing that type of work, I always keep a `tail -f orbeon.log` open somewhere, and switch back and forth between the editor, the log, and the browser.

Comment: You rigth , the log show me the error in xml file:Fatal error:                    XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.        I am cheking the files  zip-cities_mt05.xpl y zip-flat_mt03.xml .    The link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Tn41bPcuyoTnJReDJYeFZ3aEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI, your last comment is the same as the previous one. (I'm not sure if you intended to post something different, and did the wrong copy/paste.)

Comment: Sorry. Can you tell me recomendation for replicate with example with file "zip-states.xpl" but en other directory from /WEB-INF/resources/apps/xbl/orbeon/us-state to  /WEB-INF/resources/apps/xbl/orbeon/colombia.  In my case I created in the last directory  the file colombia.xbl that is a copy "us-state.xbl" I changed the value src="oxf:/xbl/orbeon/colombia/state.xml" but this is not working.  The log file is the next url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Tn41bPcuyoOWhPa2xjbS0wOWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When something doesn't work, I'd recommend you start for looking for errors in the log, read the error message(s), think, and debug. For instance in this case, there is a "xf:submission for submission id: get-itemset, error code received when submitting instance: 404". So, you can ask yourself: where is that `get-itemset` submission? why does it return a 404? what is the URL? is it happening because the URL is incorrect, or the file is really missing?

Comment: Many Thanks I am review your recomendations.